# How do I analyze movement between points in R?

Tags: r

So I have a lot of points, kind of like this:

```
animalid1;A;time
animalid1;B;time
animalid1;C;time
animalid2;A;time
animalid2;B;time
animalid2;A;time
animalid2;B;time
animalid2;C;time
animalid3;A;time
animalid3;B;time
animalid3;C;time
animalid3;B;time
animalid3;A;time
```

What I want to do is to first of all make R understand that the points A,B,C are connected. Then I want to get comparisons of movement from A to C and how long time it takes, how many steps were used, etc. So maybe I have a movement sequence like ABC on 20 animals and then ABABC on 10 animals and then ABCBA on 5 animals. I want to get some sort of statistical test done to see if the total time is different between these groups, and so on.

I bet this has been done before. But my Google skills are not good enough to find it.

Comment: As a starting point, looking at the `igraph` package might be helpful if you essentially have a network of points and want to determine trip lengths / times.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it seeks an analysis method rather than a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the msm package (msm stands for Multi State Model).  Given observations of states at different times it will estimate probabilities of transitions and average time in the different states.

Comment: This seems like an excellent method. I haven't tried it yet, but I am going to mark this answered anyway because it seems very likely that it will work. Thank you.